# Value of something with a XMLNS attribute?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have recently started fiddling around with XML and XLS mostly due to a project linked with school, and thus I have also stumbled upon a issue. Keep in mind I AM a newbie at this and the solution might be easy, but I am asking anyways

When I have something like `xsl:value-of select="name"`, it works in normal cases. However, in this scenario, it doesn't work. I have looked around in the XML file, and I have found whats causing this issue, but just removing it feels like a bad idea. Since the "name" that I am trying to select also has the attribute of XMLNS="URL", it doesn't seem to understand how to fetch it. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please show us your XSL and your XML. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I got it to work. All I did was, change `<xsl:value-of select="name">` to `<xsl:value-of select="os:name">`, then change

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

to

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:os="URL">
```

Comment: Glad to read, that you could solve your problem yourself. But please mark this answer as accepted, so other users can see, that this question is solved, thx!